# Voltage divider resistor heating up

Tags: voltage, resistors

this is my first post here pardon me if this question is idiotic :)

I made a voltage divider by following the image below

[image: Voltage Divider]

But when I connect 12v supply the resistor getting very hot just in 2seconds 
what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What else is attached? Have you verified each of the resistances with an ohmmeter?

Comment: Yes, check your resistors.  each of those 12k resistors should be dissipating about 0.003 watts, which should not cause noticeable heating of any resistor you are likely to be using.

Comment: Are you using 12 ohm and 10 ohm resistors?

Comment: k = 1000 http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/resistorcalculator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k means kilo-ohm. For example 10k means 10000 Ohms. Check by ohmmeter if you had not understood the color codes . Alternatively your voltage is higher than you think. I have done the later error by an 10x oscilloscope probe.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, 
Yes it was my mistake i took 10 Ohms resistors instead 10K
@andy-aka